# How to assign different colors to multiple markercluster groups?

Tags: css, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am working with the [leaflet.markercluster plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) and have it working so it clusters my markers. Is it possible to assign a specific color to multiple cluster groups? Right now, all the cluster marker colors are the same between various layer groups and it's hard to differientate which layers represent which.

**I want to use the default markerCluster marker styles, but I want to assign a different background-color to each group.**

Example:

Group 1

```
var trucksGroup = L.markerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        return L.divIcon({ /* assign color here?? */ });
    }
});

var carsGroup = L.markerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        return L.divIcon({ /* assign color here?? */ });
    }
});
```

The default marker CSS:

```
.marker-cluster-small {
background-color: rgba(181, 226, 140, 0.6);
}
.marker-cluster-small div {
background-color: rgba(110, 204, 57, 0.6);
}

.marker-cluster-medium {
background-color: rgba(241, 211, 87, 0.6);
}
.marker-cluster-medium div {
background-color: rgba(240, 194, 12, 0.6);
}

.marker-cluster-large {
background-color: rgba(253, 156, 115, 0.6);
}
.marker-cluster-large div {
background-color: rgba(241, 128, 23, 0.6);
}`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried it this, but here's what I recommend attempting:

1. Instead of returning `L.divIcon()` from your function, get the default icon by calling `_defaultIconCreateFunction()` on your `markerClusterGroup`, e.g., `trucksGroup._defaultIconCreateFunction(cluster)`.
2. Add a new class to that default icon to denote what group it's in. E.g., `icon.options.className += ' trucks-group'`.
3. Add new styles in your CSS for `.truck-group.marker-cluster-small`, `.truck-group.marker-cluster-medium`, etc.

Putting the first two steps together:

```
var trucksGroup = L.markerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        var icon = trucksGroup._defaultIconCreateFunction(cluster);
        icon.options.className += ' trucks-group';
        return icon;
    }
});

var carsGroup = L.markerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        var icon = carsGroup._defaultIconCreateFunction(cluster);
        icon.options.className += ' cars-group';
        return icon;
    }
});
```

Comment: My cluster icons ended up square when I folowed this, becuase there was no `trucks-group.marker-cluster`, so I inherited, with `marker-cluster, <new line>.trucks-group.marker-cluster` and that inherited the shape.